How to transfer program to another computer without active license key?
I got this email from the current owner of a software program, iMacros, that I have used to create dozens of macros which I use every day in my business:                                                                   "We are writing to you as a final reminder that we will decommission (shut down) the iMacros license server on November 30, 2024.
"As your license(s) are perpetual, you can choose to continue using the existing iMacros product that you have installed “as-is” under your existing licenses. However, you will no longer be able to move your iMacros licenses to another machine after November 30, 2024."
I have asked program owner for solution and they don't have one.  So Is there any way to create a backup now that I can use to load then run on a new computer bypassing above license issue if original machine crashes in future?

It all depends HOW the activation of their software works. My suggestion is that perpetual has a very specific meaning. I would request a refund if they cannot actually provide a perpetual license

I would contact the devs and ask if there's a way to export the macros to another software solution, and completely migrate away from it.

Another less powerful option is to create a VM, and transfer the license to inside that VM. As long as that VM works, you can transfer it to any computer. The downside is that the macros can only be used inside the VM, so unless you can transfer your work into the VMs too, it will be pointless. At least you can use this to have the macros there so you can view what they did, and recreate them in another software program.

We really can't answer this as we are not the devs of the product.

It depends on how the license is enforced.
A full drive image is a definite first step, and likely is all you'd need to reinstall onto the same computer if it's drive is damaged or dies.
There are many third-party tools to make disk images, such as Linux dd, DriveImage XML, and alternatives. Some are free, some not. Some work on one operating system which should be included in the question, some on others.
That said, a drive image might not help on another PC. Perhaps it could be mounted in a virtual machine, but, unless the new PC is identical to the old, it might not be directly deployed to the PC. However, you have until iMacros' deadline to test the image on another PC.
